# Modern Intel CPUs serial communication

Tags: linux, serial-port

I have Intel X299 Chipset system that runs a linux system that prints boot log to the serial port, How can I connect to the serial port and read the data? modern motherboards doesn't have RS232 input.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a converter.

Comment: David is talking about a USB to Serial Port device.

Comment: The usb port is the serial port? which one of them? how it can used for two different purposes?